# Change iMessage Sticker Pack Asset based on Light/Dark Mode?

Tags: xcode, assets, imessage, ios-darkmode, imessage-extension

I am wondering if it's at all possible to change an asset used in an iMessage sticker pack based on Light/Dark Mode like you can in a normal asset. If so, how can I do that? And would it require using a custom sticker presenter instead of the standard/built-in one? Thank you!

Comment: I have searched everywhere for information about this and I don't think you can...which is so strange. Sticker assets should behave like regular assets...at least when you send to other Mac devices.